# Simple drag-to-create functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a very simple best-fit scheduling system.  Everyone submits their free/busy times via a web-based form, the system suggests times when the most people are free.

I'm currently trying to figure out a good way to collect this input from users.  Ideally, I'd like to duplicate the kind of functionality you see in Google Calendar - given a view of a calendar, the user clicks their start time, drags the cursor to the end time, releases the mouse button, and in the box that pops up, adds a one or two word summary describing that block of time.

I looked at jQuery's "droppable" but it didn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

[This would be great](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range-vertical), but I'd need some way to put an arbitrary number of sliders on one line to represent start-end times.

Does anyone know {a jQuery way, a good way, a simple way} of gathering an arbitrary number of start-end times and their associated descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?
http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/qHxZ6/